# Xamarin Xamarin.Android Xamarin.iOS - End of Support

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image: Xamarin Releases End of Support]

I'm looking for official and up-to-date information about Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS End of Support.

The official Microsoft page seems obsolete as lastest Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS are not listed.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin

Anyone having a link to the official information about:

- Last Xamarin.Android version ever released and End of Support.
- Last Xamarin.iOS version ever released and End of Support.
- Official .NET 6 for Android release date and End of Support.
- Official .NET 6 for iOS release date and End of Support.

Comment: You can check it out on github. Android(https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android). iOS(https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios).

Answer (score 1):

There are descriptions about the end of support in the [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin)

> At least two years from last release date, or newer release.

And the latest stable version of xamarin.ios is `14.0.0.0`, it released in **September 21, 2020**.

the latest stable version of xamarin.android is `12.1.99.117`, it released in **January 5, 2022**.

Comment: In fact the latest stable version of xamarin.ios seems to be 14.9
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/

For xamarin.android, the last stable version seems to be 12.1 even what the "release-notes" page says, this page seems not up to date.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/

Xamarin release support policies says the current releases are supported 2 years after initial release.

Does it concern only the first major version ?

For e.g. for Xamarin.iOS, the initial release of the current version concerns 14.0 or 14.9 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest update I found today and seems they are not planning to continue with Xamarin.

It would be good to start the migration from Xamarin.forms to .Net MAUI ASAP now.

I don't think we will able to migrate Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android projects. So for that, we have to start from scratch with another tech.

[image]

---

---

[image]

Check the latest update [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin#:%7E:text=Xamarin%20support%20will%20end%20on,about%20upgrading%20Xamarin%20projects%20to%20.).